# Let HTML tags in summary

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, removeclass

in my blogger template, i have a script which creates short summaries with thumbs in my posts grid. It calculates the number of characters shown with and without thumbs and put a "read more" link at the bottom...

My problem is that it removes the HTML tags in the summary. For example, if i have a list (**ul** / **il**) in the post, it does not show, it makes a plain text. I would like it that it leaves the html tags as they are originally in the posts but keeps the 500 (without thumb) and 300 (with thumb) characters long.

I guess i must change the line `removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ)` bu I can not figure out how to do it...

My blog : http://ildesign-blogger-demo-1.blogspot.fr/

The whole script :

```
posts_no_thumb_sum = 500;
posts_thumb_sum = 300;
img_thumb_height = 150;
img_thumb_width = 150;


//<![CDATA[
function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){
if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1)
{
var s = strx.split("<");
for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){
s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length);
}
}
strx = s.join("");
}
chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2;
while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++;
strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1);
return strx+'...';
}
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
var div = document.getElementById(pID);
var imgtag = "";
var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
var summ = posts_no_thumb_sum;
if(img.length>=1) {
imgtag = '<span class="posts-thumb"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></span>';
summ = posts_thumb_sum;
}
var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
div.innerHTML = summary;
}
//]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't call removeHtmlTag method. Instead of

```
    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
```

Do:

```
    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + div.innerHTML + '</div>';
```

Comment: I already tried... If i do this, my whole post will be shown, it is not a summary anymore. I would like if the summary remains 500 & 300 characters long.

Comment: Can you show what removeHtmlTag method actually does: It looks like it is doing more than just stripping html tags. I think it is also restricting the post to 300 characters. If that is the case, you will need to create another method, maybe restrictCharacters that just keeps first 300 characters from your body and then you just need to replace removeHtmlTag method with the new method.

Comment: Look, the first two lines of the codes make 500 characters for posts who do not have image and 300 characters for which do have images. You can see on my blog how it is now : http://ildesign-blogger-demo-1.blogspot.fr/